# Listing module under one custom module heading

Tags: routes

I have created Menu type called Form submission. Under this I want to list all the Form submitted values. There are two forms one is Contact form and help form. I want to display these two as Contact and help form under the menu type Form submission.

Example: When I click Contact it has to show the contact list.

How to list the Contact and help form under the Form submission in admin page. I build it as custom module.

Comment: what you mean by 'Listing module' under Form submission menu?. Do you want to just list all form submissions under a menu? if so what kind of form you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your question actually relates to adding new custom entries to the admin menu, in which case this article may help: http://drupalst.com/blog/add-menu-block-administrator-configuration-page (it's specifically about the config menu but any part of the admin menu can be customized in a similar manner).

Answer (score 0):

You can print any form using [drupal_get_form](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/drupal_get_form/7)

```
drupal_get_form($form_id)
```

And to print a form

```
<?php print drupal_render(drupal_get_form($form_id)); ?>
```

You can find form id using [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7)

Eg :

```
function YOURMODULENAME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  echo $form_id;
}
```

To redirect users after submission you can use [drupal_redirect_form](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/drupal_redirect_form/7)

> Redirects the user to a URL after a form has been processed.

To get all modules list you can use [module_list](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/module_list/7)

> Returns a list of currently active modules.

Comment: how to show all custom modules under one menu using hook_menu

Comment: As we see admin>> structure>>

Comment: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/module_list/7

Comment: I'm not clear with that. Please help me out

Comment: I am also not clear about your requirement. Do you want all modules list in your menu ?

Comment: @sindhu My pleasure.